# Realizar agrupamento de tabela com dois parâmetros

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

boa noite.
Ainda estou aprendendo banco de dados e gostaria de tirar uma dúvida com vocês.

Sei que se eu quiser organizar minha tabela com os valores faturados por mês, posso usar o group by e filtra-la dessa forma:

```
SELECT to_char(DATA, 'YYYY-MM') as MES, sum(QTDUSUARIOS) as QTDUSUARIOS, sum(VALORFATURADO) as VALORFATURADO 
from UBER 
group by to_char(DATA, 'YYYY-MM') order by 1;
```

e obter um resultado assim:

```
MES           QTDUSUARIOS     VALORFATURADO

2018-01       244             3.000
2018-02       900             2.500
2018-03       320             1.000
```

Mas supondo que eu precise também agrupar por município e mês,
ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
MES           QTDUSUARIOS       MUNICIPIO       VALORFATURADO

2018-01       136               SERRA            2.000
2018-01       108               CAMBURI          1.000
2018-02       500               SERRA            1.000
2018-02       400               CAMBURI          1.500
2018-03       200               SERRA            500
2018-03       120               CAMBURI          500
```

Como faria para agrupar dessa forma? Tentei adicionar mais parâmetros no meu group by, mas sempre gera um erro dizendo que o comando não foi encerrado adequadamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem conhecer toda a estrutura da tabela diria que será algo deste género:

```
SELECT      TO_CHAR(DATA, 'YYYY-MM')    AS MES
        ,   SUM(QTDUSUARIOS)            AS QTDUSUARIOS
        ,   MUNICIPIO
        ,   SUM(VALORFATURADO)          AS VALORFATURADO 
FROM        UBER 
GROUP BY    TO_CHAR(DATA, 'YYYY-MM')
        ,   MUNICIPIO
ORDER BY    1
```